# Flutter Http request Header Key lowercase

Tags: flutter, dart, post

In the flutter to make http post request, header key into a full small write

```
user-agent: Dart/2.10 (dart:io)
content-type: application/json
accept-encoding: gzip
content-length: 46
```

There is a way to set the initials capital?

```
User-Agent: Dart/2.10 (dart:io)
Content-Type: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 46
```

I changed the Header again when I posted the request，The service side receives it, print it out or it's small。

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use Dio, in this case, I use Dio v.4.0.

1. Find the io_adapter.dart file in the Dio package directory, i suggest you use Intellij IDEA or Android Studio.

   [io_adapter.dart file location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zq3kq.png)
2. Find the code snippet as below

   ```
   options.headers.forEach((k, v) => request.headers.set(k, v));
   ```
3. Replace with this code

   ```
   options.headers.forEach((k, v) {
    request.headers.set(k, v??"null",preserveHeaderCase: true);      });
   ```
4. Flutter clean and rebuild your Flutter App
5. Done

Ref. https://github.com/flutterchina/dio/issues/641

Answer (score 0):

In Latest Dio, u can easily Allow case-sensitive header keys with the preserveHeaderCase flag through options, For Example:

```
Dio().options.preserveHeaderCase = true;
```